# Ruby on Rails - get Linux Root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.8.7

I am simply trying to get the root path to look up a file on my machine, I am pretty new to RoR. Is there some sort of variable somewhere so I could do something like this:

```
def path
    return '{#ROOT}/some/path/file.txt'
end
```

I do not want the Rails root, I want the machine root.

Comment: The "machine root" is `/`, I don't understand the issue. The return is redundant. Single-quoted strings aren't interpolated.

Comment: What do you mean "machine root". In unix that's always /

Comment: oooh... I haven't touched unix in years! :)

Comment: I like return... bad C# habit I suppose

Comment: Yeah, drop that habit ;-)

Comment: Also, if the tag's correct, you need to drop ruby 1.8.7 too!!

Comment: not my choice on the version :P

Comment: If it's a constant, make it one, even if you need a method to return it-then it's easily mocked. Or make it part of your configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace your method with:

```
def path
  "/some/path/file.txt"
end
```

Since root is always /, and return isn't necessary in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the file path, and not the URL path, this will provide the absolute file path of your rails root folder:

```
Rails.root
```

From there, you could simple add on the rails path to your file, as your rails directory structure should be static:

```
def path
    return "{#Rails.root}/some/path/file.txt"
end
```

Comment: any explanation as to the down-vote would be very constructive

Comment: Thanks, Fixed. I had just copy & pasted that from the question

Comment: Also, it says right in the question that they didn't want the rails root. So, per the OP, this doesn't answer their question.